# Searching through a Hashtable

Tags: .net

I have a Hashtable containing key and data in the following format.

```
Key            Data
--------------------
X1    ---- >   D1
X2    ---- >   D1
X3    ---- >   D1
X4    ---- >   D2
X5    ---- >   D2
X6    ---- >   D3
```

My requirement is to get a tree structure from the same data

i.e

```
D1
|------- X1
|--------X2
|--------X3

D2
|------- X4
|--------X5

D3
|------- X6
```

Can anyone help out with the logic ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not a .net person but I think you need to elaborate. Are you trying to print out that structure? Or you trying to convert a map of key => data into a hierarchy of tree node objects? What exactly are you needing help with? The code to convert or advice on how best to convert?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, string>() 
{
    { "X1", "D1"},
    { "X2", "D1"},
    { "X3", "D2"},
};

var transform = data.GroupBy(m => m.Value)
                    .ToDictionary(m => m.Key, m => m.Select( g => g.Key )
                    .ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something this .

```
Hashtable  theHash;
theHash = new Hashtable();

theHash.Add("d1", new Hashtable());
theHash.Add("d2", new Hashtable());
theHash.Add("d3", new Hashtable());

Hashtable activeChild;
activeChild = (Hashtable)theHash["d1"];

activeChild.Add("x1", "myvalue");
activeChild.Add("x2", "myvalue2");
activeChild.Add("x3", "myvalue3");
```